# Swift SearchBar how to get original search icon after it was changed programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

Im currently using a `searchBar` i changed the left icon to a custom UIImageView. when button is pressed I want to change it back to the original search icon.

```
//my custom search iconBar 
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named:"img1"), for: .search, state: .normal)

func changeSearchBarIconBackToOriginal {
//searchbar icon should be back to original image here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would store the last image in a variable, and set the search bar's icon to that when the button is pressed.

Example:

```
var lastIcon: UIImage?

...

lastIcon = searchBar.image(for: .search, state: .normal)
searchBar.setImage(UIImage("img"), for: .search, state: .normal)
```

Then, in the function when it's pressed:
    func changeSearchBarIconBackToOriginal() {
        searchBar.setImage(lastIcon, for: .search, state: .normal)
    }